# Integer subtraction with wrap around for N bits

Tags: c++, math, bit-manipulation, subtraction

Basically, the behavior you get when overflowing integers with subtraction, but for a given number of bits. The obvious way, assuming a **signed** integer:

```
template <int BITS>
int sub_wrap(int v, int s) {
  int max = (1<<(BITS));
  v -= s;
  if (v < -max) v += max*2;
  // or if branching is bad, something like:
  // v += (max*2) * (v < -max)
  return v;
}

// For example subtracting 24 from -16 with 5 bit wrap,
// with a range of -32, 31
sub_wrap<5>(-16, 28); -> 20
```

Is there a neat way of doing it that is less ugly and preferably faster than the one above?

UPDATE: Sorry about the confusion. I thoughtlessly included the confusing notation of using the number of bits excluding the sigh bit. So in the above, replace 5 bits with 6 bits for a lot more sanity.

Comment: You also need to check for `v >= max`.

Comment: A range of -32 to 31 requires 6 bits, not 5.

Comment: That depends entirely on your point of view. I'm just used to denoting the number of bits excluding the sign in the code I'm currently using, but I guess that is just confusing.

Answer (score 8):

For unsigned arithmetic, and mask the results, e.g.:

```
template<int bits>
unsigned
sub_wrap( unsigned v, unsigned s )
{
    return (v - s) & ((1 << bits) - 1);
}
```

More generally, you can use the modulo operator:

```
template<int modulo>
unsigned
sub_wrap( unsigned v, unsigned s )
{
    return (v - s) % modulo;
}
```

(Wrapping on `n` bits is the equivalent of modulo 2^n.)

For signed arithmetic, it's a bit more complex; using the mask, you'll have to sign extend the results (supposing 2's complement).

EDIT: Using sehe's suggestion for signed arithmetic:

```
template<int bits>
int
sub_wrap( int v, int s )
{
    struct Bits { signed int r: bits; } tmp;
    tmp.r = v - s;
    return tmp.r;
}
```

Given this, `sub_wrap<5>( -16, 28 )` gives `-12` (which is correct—note that `28` cannot be represented as signed int in 5 bits); `sub_wrap<6>( -16, 28 )` gives `20`.

Comment: Your code never produces negative values, which seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Alex Judging from his example, that's what he wants, but according to what he wrote, it's not clear.  My code is what I would consider the "classical" solution, for modulo arithmetic over a range `[0,2^n)`, but for modulo arithmetic, I would use unsigned integral types.  @sehe's suggestion is, however, quite clever, and works for signed types as well.

Comment: +1 for trying some more and (a) pointing out that I should not have taken the sample from the OP at face value (b) showing that bitfields _can_ be varied based on a const template argument (weehoo: never underestimate the power of C++)

Comment: @JamesKanze: from the OP's code it follows that the resultant range is expected to include negative numbers as well. See `if (v < -max) v += max*2;`.

Comment: Thanks for this clean answer, and sorry for the confusing example. I put up [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313265/how-does-the-compiler-implement-bit-field-arithmetics) regarding how this will perform.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose this should work:

```
 struct bits
 {
     signed int field : 5;
 };

 bits a = { -16 };     
 bits b = {  28 };

 bits c = { a.field - b.field };
 std::cout << c.field << std::endl;
```

<strike>I'm pretty sure the field width won't work with a const template argument... and hence this is less generic. It should, however, avoid manual tinkering. Will post test soon</strike>

**Update** It turns out my answer wasn't incorrect after all. It is just that the sample input (28) cannot be represented in 5 bits (signed). The outcome of the above is -12 (**see http://ideone.com/AUrXy**).

Here is, for completeness, a templated version after all:

```
template<int bits>
int sub_wrap(int v, int s)
{
    struct helper { signed int f: bits; } tmp = { v };
    return (tmp.f -= s);
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, assigning back and then returning the field from the `struct` would work.  This may be the simplest solution for signed values.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't know what exactly you meant, but this seems to indicate it wouldn't work: http://ideone.com/AUrXy

Comment: As written, it won't work, but if you declare the bit field `signed int`, assign the computed value back into it, and then return the value from the bit field, it should work (and does for me).

Comment: Whether bit fields are signed or unsigned by default is implementation defined.

Comment: @interjay: spot on  (§ 9.6, sub 3). Fixed;

Comment: @JamesKanze: sigh. I got quite confused here. I was already assigning back into the bit field (`c.field`...) but the sample from the OP wasn't well-chosen

Comment: +1 for templating bitfields! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c/1771843#1771843

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it w/o conditional branches and multiplication:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Assumptions:
// - ints are 32-bit
// - signed ints are 2's complement
// - right shifts of signed ints are sign-preserving arithmetic shifts
// - signed overflows are harmless even though strictly speaking they
//   result in undefined behavior
//
// Requirements:
// - 0 < bits <= 32
int sub_wrap(int v, int s, unsigned bits)
{
  int d = v - s;
  unsigned m = ~0u >> (32 - bits);
  int r = d & m | -((d >> (bits - 1)) & 1) & ~m;
  return r;
}

#define BITS 2

int main(void)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = -(1 << (BITS - 1)); i <= (1 << (BITS - 1)) - 1; i++)
    for (j = -(1 << (BITS - 1)); j <= (1 << (BITS - 1)) - 1; j++)
      printf("%d - %d = %d\n", i, j, sub_wrap(i, j, BITS));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-2 - -2 = 0
-2 - -1 = -1
-2 - 0 = -2
-2 - 1 = 1
-1 - -2 = 1
-1 - -1 = 0
-1 - 0 = -1
-1 - 1 = -2
0 - -2 = -2
0 - -1 = 1
0 - 0 = 0
0 - 1 = -1
1 - -2 = -1
1 - -1 = -2
1 - 0 = 1
1 - 1 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This simulates an n bit integer operation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template< typename T >
T sub_wrap(T a, T b, int nBits)
{
        T topBit, mask, tmp;

        topBit=T(1) << (nBits-1);
        mask=(topBit << 1)-1;
        tmp=((a&mask)+((~b+1)&mask))&mask;
        if (tmp & topBit) tmp=-((~tmp&mask)+1);

        return tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        std::cout << sub_wrap< int >(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]))
                << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
$ ./sim 5 6 4
-1
$ ./sim 7 3 4
4
$ ./sim 7 -1 4
-8
$ ./sim -16 28 4
4
$ ./sim -16 28 5
-12
$ ./sim -16 28 6
20
```

Seems you miscalculated your type size by 1 bit.