# Variable declaration in the switch head?

Tags: c++

While browsing the code of my friend I came to notice this:

```
switch(State &state = getState()) {
case Begin: state = Search; break;
// other stuff similar
}
```

What is with the variable in the switch header? He is using GCC so I think this might be a GCC extension. Any idea?

Comment: The code block starts with the opening curly brace, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Is this one of your trick questions? I sense something drastic coming our way by the time this Q has an accepted answer :-]

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it was Johannes... I feel tricked into answering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a secret or a GCC extension. Variables are allowed to be declared in the conditions of things like `if`s, `while`s, and `switch`es. For example:

```
while (char c = cin.get()) { ... }
```

or

```
if (int* something = (int*)malloc(4)) { // but don't use malloc in C++
    // ...
}
```

After they are declared an initialised, they are converted to a `bool` value and if they evaluate to `true` the block is executed, and the block is skipped otherwise. Their scope is that of the construct whose condition they are declared in (and in the case of `if`, the scope is also over all the `else if` and `else` blocks too).

In §6.4.1 of the C++03 standard, it says

> Selection statements choose one of several flows of control.
>
> ```
> selection-statement:
>
>     if ( condition ) statement
>     if ( condition ) statement else statement
>     switch ( condition ) statement
>
> condition:
>
>     expression
>     type-specifier-seq declarator = assignment-expression
> ```

So as you can see, it allows `type-specifier-seq declarator = assignment-expression` in the condition of an `if` or `switch`. And you'd find something similar in the section for the "repetition constructs".

Also, `switch`es work on integral or `enum` types *or* instances of classes that can be implicitly converted to an integral or `enum` type (§6.4.4):

> The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a
> switch statement is the value of the declared variable if it has
> integral or enumeration type, or of that variable implicitly converted
> to integral or enumeration type otherwise.

I actually learned of this [**FROM AN ANSWER YOU POSTED**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312449/726361) on the "Hidden Features of C++" question. So I'm glad I could remind you of it :)

Comment: Yeah but it is on a `switch()`, which it means that it only accepts `int` values ?

Comment: @Muggen in the example `State` is an `enum` probably.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb no, but your lack of capitalisation indicates that you are asking a question to which you already know the answer :)

Comment: @Seth, if it is not an enum, would behaviour like that be possible if the `operator int()` was overloaded ?

Comment: @Muggen yeah, apparently if it can be converted into an integral value then it will work too.

Comment: @Muggen yeah, the standard says `The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a switch statement is
the value of the declared variable if it has integral or enumeration type, or of that variable implicitly converted to integral or enumeration type otherwise.`

Comment: How can you switch on a reference?

Comment: @John references are transparent; it's switching on a `State`.

Comment: *"Variables are allowed to be declared in the conditions"* ... Damn it.