# Printing uppercase letters using 'if'

Tags: c++, ascii

What did I do wrong? I need this, to print all uppercase letters using 'if', but something is wrong because it is printing a letter more than once! Any help appreciated :)

```
//Uppercase letters using if;
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char character='A';
label1:
if(character>='A')
    if(character>='Z')
        goto label2;
    else
    {
        cout<<character<<endl<<character++<<endl;
        goto label1;
    }

label2:
    cout<<"End"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programmers. This is off-topic here and belongs on StackOverflow. Please don't re-ask it there as this can be migrated. A good rule to follow is if your question has you in front of your IDE it belongs on SO. If it has in front of a whiteboard it belongs on Programmers. Please take a moment to read the site's [FAQ] to learn more about asking question here.

Comment: also WTH are you using goto? learn about loops and try not to use gotos they are almost **never** needed

Comment: Those `goto` statements are realllly unnecessary.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: lol, I know about loops, but this is what the assignment said to use!

Comment: Wait, you *have* to use goto instead of a proper loop? That's absurd!

Comment: Seriously, if they *make* you write code like this, get a new instructor/school/book/etc.

Comment: @NPE, New school? Talk about ragequitting!

Comment: @chris: If that's the level of tuition, this may be the only way forward! :) (nice word, BTW)

Comment: If I had to use `goto`, I would name my label `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful`.

Comment: @All: Thanks; Just started C++ class from the ground(zero), we came down here so far, so he gave us this assignment "Print all uppercase letters using if(goto)" :(

Comment: @chris: good one, it would even compile. in your `goto` statement you would have to replace `:` with `;`, but i guess it would not be that cumbersome if using `goto` is considered acceptable at all

Comment: @AndyProwl, I have some "Cool features of C++" question on SO to thank for that, but I'm having trouble finding it!

Comment: Note that you'll never print the uppercase "Z".

Comment: @chris: if you do, please share!

Comment: @AndyProwl, There it was, a side link off of one I found on Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c?lq=1

Comment: @chris: analog literals made my day. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You increase the `character` variable twice. I am posting this answer just to show you what is the technical mistake, but there is a much bigger conceptual one, which is the use of `goto`. I suggest you to read some introductory book on C++.

```
//Uppercase letters using if;
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char character='A';

label1:
if(character>='A')
    if(character>'Z'))
        goto label2;
    else
    {
        cout<<character<<endl;
        character++;
        goto label1;
    }

label2:
    cout<<"End"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently the assignment requests him to use `goto`... `gofigure`

Comment: Still will never print "Z".

Comment: It would have been sufficient to change `>=` to `>`.

Comment: @HotLicks: true. i was just lazy to think too much, i thought the answer made the point clear enough

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's printing each letter more than once is the following:

```
    cout<<character<<endl<<character++<<endl;
          ^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Each of the above would result in `character` getting written to `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    if (1) goto label1;
    cout << "End" << endl;
    return 0;
label1:
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Brad Thank you very much: I was sure I was going to get massively *down* voted. You gave me a good laugh there :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code missed two points -

1. it was not printing `Z`
2. printing character two times `cout<<character<<endl<<character++<<endl;`

change:
  `if(character>='Z')` **to ->** `if(character>'Z')`

**EDITED** character++ ( that was typo)
 `cout<<character<<endl<<character++<<endl;` **to ->** `cout<<character++<<endl;`

Comment: the changes you mention are not enough, as it would never end up increasing `character`. it is also needed to add a `character++` after the `cout` statement.