# Unnamed struct declaration inside for loop initialization statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct, anonymous-class

In one of the SO thread, I had seen a usage of unnamed `struct` acting as a placeholder for multiple variables of different types inside for loop:

For example:

```
for(struct {
      int i;
      double d;
      char c;
    } obj = { 1, 2.2, 'c' };
    obj.i < 10;
    ++obj.i)
{
  ...
}
```

This [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/UfGtIM) with g++.
Is this a standard C++03 syntax?

Comment: I'm pretty darn sure it is.

Comment: + interesting, its also possible in c99

Comment: Ah, found it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/889001/962089

Comment: And use `decltype(obj)` in the loop to have other variables too!

Answer (score 3):

You can use an unnamed struct anywhere you can use a struct - the only difference is that it doesn't get a name that can be used somewhere else. You can declare a new type anywhere you can use a type, pretty much. It may not be particularly meaningful to do so in most places, but that's another matter.

I wouldn't exactly recommend this, other than in very special cases, but it's valid.

Comment: "you can declare a new type anywhere you can use a type" Not in template calls ;)

Answer (score -1):

Below code will work in C++ (g++  5.4.0).

> http://rextester.com/ELWLF59792

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
      int i = 0;

      for(struct st{ int a[9]; }t;i<3;i++)
            printf("%d\n", t.a);
}
```

And below code will work in C (gcc  5.4.0).

```
//gcc 5.4.0

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
      int i = 0;
      struct st{ int a[9]; }t;
      for(;i<3;i++)
            printf("%d\n", t.a);
}
```

Comment: What's the meaning of such code? printing `t.a`? Looping only till 3 ?

Comment: It's clear in the code that it's counter's value is true for i=0,1,2. So it is printing 3 times.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", t.a);` will always print the address of `t.a` (i.e. `&t.a[0]`) - why loop?

Comment: Sorry **@Ajay**, mistakenly I answered another question's answer here. I will check and change my answer. Thanks.